# Using MapProxy to convert WMTS to WMS or TMS

Tags: mapproxy

I am trying to configure MapProxy to enable me to access a WMTS service via WMS or TMS.  Here is the source WMTS service:

```
http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ovln19YRWV44nBqV/arcgis/rest/services/ScottIA_2014Aerial/MapServer
```

Here is my MapProxy instance:

```
http://104.197.62.82:8080/demo/
```

Here is my MapProxy configuration file:

```
services:
   demo:
   tms:
   wms:
layers:
 - name: scott_layer
   title: Scott
   sources: [scott_cache]
caches:
   scott_cache:
      grids: [scott_grid]
      sources: [scott_source]
sources:
   scott_source:
      type: tile
      grid: scott_grid
      url: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ovln19YRWV44nBqV/arcgis/rest/services/ScottIA_2014Aerial/MapServer/tile/%(z)s/%(y)s/%(x)s
grids:
   scott_grid:
      origin: 'nw'
      bbox: [2341500.5208333135, 533999.4791666567, 2517000.5208333135, 662999.4791666567]
      srs: 'EPSG:3426'
      res: [
         #  res            level     scale @90.7 DPI
          868.0555554189, #  0     3100198.41221019
          434.0277777094, #  1     1550099.20610510
          217.0138888547, #  2      775049.60305255
          108.5069444274, #  3      387524.80152627
           55.5555555468, #  4      198412.69838145
           27.7777777734, #  5       99206.34919073
           13.8888888867, #  6       49603.17459536
            6.9444444434, #  7       24801.58729768
            4.1666666660, #  8       14880.95237861
            2.0833333330, #  9        7440.47618930
            1.0416666665, # 10        3720.23809465
            0.5208333333, # 11        1860.11904733
      ]
```

If you use the MapProxy demo link above, you will see that nothing is showing up on the map.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Update:

I ultimately want to display the source map in Google Maps.  I can do that if the source map is a tile service that uses the standard Google Maps tiling scheme.  I can also do that if the source map is WMS.  The challenge here is that this source map uses a custom tiling scheme (see http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ovln19YRWV44nBqV/arcgis/rest/services/ScottIA_2014Aerial/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml).  Therefore, I cannot find a way to display the tiles in Google Maps.  I was hoping to use MapProxy to convert this WMTS source map with a custom tiling scheme into WMS or TMS (TMS uses a tiling scheme compatible with Google Maps).

Comment: have you manage to soleve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Looking for an answer to this as well. Not everyone can consume WMTS and some legacy software packages require WMS. (AutoCAD)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163032)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163032)

Answer (score 2):

What client won't consume WMTS
Which is basically Google XYZ TILE Schema
You just first try connecting your map client to this

https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/ovln19YRWV44nBqV/arcgis/rest/services/ScottIA_2014Aerial/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/ScottIA_2014Aerial/{Style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.jpeg

If that does not work replace.tilematrix.with zoom

Or XYZ.JPG

WMS is going to be super slow when this is already tiled